# Как распараллелить цикл получения яркости пикселей Bitmap?

Tags: c#, распараллеливание

Собственно я пытаюсь распараллелить данный цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            brightness += img.GetPixel(j, i).GetBrightness();
        }
}
```

данным образом:

```
Parallel.For(0, totalPixels, i =>
                {
                        int y = i / width, x = i % height;
                        brightness += img.GetPixel(x, y).GetBrightness();
                });
```

но компилятор выдает исключение:

```
System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: В данный момент объект используется другим процессом.
   в System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   в System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32 x, Int32 y)
   в PhotoTravelDemonstrationProject.ImageProcessing.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBrightness>b__0(Int32 i) в c:\Users\3StYleR\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhotoTravelDemonstrationProject\PhotoTravelDemonstrationProject\ImageProcessing.cs:строка 49
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__f(Object param0)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я накосячил и как можно исправить/переделать распараллеливание данного цикла.

Comment: Вы используете изначально медленную операцию GetPixel. Распараллеливание не даст прироста. Лучше использовать функции, которые получают все изображение в массив сразу.

Comment: То есть записать изображение в массив Color[,], а уже его обработку распараллелить?

Comment: думаю да. Вполне возможно, что скорость Вас понравиться даже без распаралелливания.

Comment: Вы _не можете_ использовать `System.Drawing.Image` из нескольких потоков одновременно, он доступен только в том потоке, которые его создал. Вытащите нужную информацию в другую структуру.

Answer (score 1):

img шарится между потоками и никак не защищен от повреждающей модификации.